# Unable to install mysqldiff on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, 20.04

Since I've upgraded my system to 20.04 mysqldiff is missing.
I found this package:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/mysqldiff.1.html
but if I try to install it with apt, but it can't find it.

`sudo apt install  mysql-utilities`

Neither its dependency found by apt:
python-mysql.connector (>= 1.2.1) 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/mysql-utilities/1.6.4-1

When I try to search mysql-utilities, it says:

```
$ apt-cache search mysql-utilities
libmysql-diff-perl - module for comparing the table structure of two MySQL databases
```

I also tried to install libmysql-diff-perl (just like before probably) but no mysqldiff command available.

Anyone faced with the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package is not available for 20.04 LTS because of Python 2 deprecation, but you can still install it using packages from 19.10:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/mysqldiff
cd ~/Downloads/mysqldiff
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-nacl/python-nacl_1.3.0-2_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pyodbc/python-pyodbc_4.0.22-1build2_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/paramiko/python-paramiko_2.6.0-1_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/antlr4-cpp-runtime/libantlr4-runtime4.7.2_4.7.2+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler90_0.80.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/netcdf/libnetcdf13_4.6.2-1build1_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/proj/libproj13_5.2.0-1_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgeotiff-dfsg/libgeotiff2_1.4.3-1_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gdal/gdal-data_2.4.2+dfsg-1build2_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gdal/libgdal20_2.4.2+dfsg-1build2_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mysql-connector-python/python-mysql.connector_8.0.15-1_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-data_8.0.17+dfsg-1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench_8.0.17+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mysql-utilities/mysql-utilities_1.6.4-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

then pin libgdal packages with to prevent removal of just installed packages:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-gdal
Package: gdal-data
Pin: version 2.4.2+dfsg-1build2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libgdal20
Pin: version 2.4.2+dfsg-1build2
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

and enjoy:

> ```
> $ mysqldiff --version
> MySQL Utilities mysqldiff version 1.6.4 
> License type: GPLv2
> ```

Also you will get `mysql-workbench` installed as dependency and as free bonus :)

Comment: The download link is no longer working

Comment: @PayelSenapati which exactly link does not work for you?

Comment: "packages from 19.10" link in your answer for download of mysqldiff package. It opens an Error page stating - "two or more packages specified (mysql-utilities eoan)"

Comment: Thanks, answer is now updated. It is still fully functional.